# Select rows with same id but same value in another column

Tags: sql

I have the data in a table as follows

```
Account_id Batch_source
_________________________
9010144 AWS-RFF    
9010144 AWS    
9010144 AWS    
9010144 AWS    
9010144 AWS    
9010144 AWS    
9010144 AWS    
9414363 AWS-RFF    
9414363 AWS-RFF    
9414363 AWS-RFF    
9414363 AWS-RFF    
9414363 AWS-RFF    
9414363 AWS-RFF
```

I should only get 9414363 as it has all the values in column batch_source contains RFF. Though 9010144 is having a column which contains RFF it should not come in out put as it is having other values as well.

Tried count(distinct(batch_source)) but the problem is i can get other account_id which have all column values as 'AWS' which qualifies the below criteria. I need the rows which has all values in batch_source column contains RFF

```
SELECT account_id, (batch_source) AS id_group
FROM MyTable
group by batch_source,account_id 
having count(distinct(batch_source)) = 1 ;
```

Comment: Are you trying to find account which have only a single batch value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your query below and updated it such that it returns the expected results.

```
 SELECT account_id, max(batch_source) AS id_group
 FROM MyTable group by account_id 
 having count(distinct(batch_source)) = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
select account_id, batch_source AS id_group
from MyTable
group by batch_source,account_id 
having min(batch_source) = max(batch_source) and
       min(batch_source) like '%-RFF';
```

If you wanted to ensure the RFF suffix, but don't care about the prefix, then count the number of misses and be sure it is zero:

```
having sum(case when batch_source not like '%-RFF' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The `= 0` says that all rows in the group have an RFF suffix.

Comment: This also helpful but its like my original query and in my enviromnent i cant configure the like clause